# Make custom field become required when certain condition is fulfilled

Tags: community, picklist, validation-rule, required-field

Could you please advise and give an example of a validation rule to help me make a custom field required when picklist value is selected.

I have a picklist called Type and a custom field called Description.

The Description field should become required only if picklist value “Other” is selected.

Could you please advise and give an example of how such restriction can be achieved?

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: You've tagged it yourself: with a validation rule

Comment: Ok, but could you please give an example of a validation rule to help me achieve what I need? 
What I need is to make the Description field become required only if picklist value “Other” is selected.

Answer (score 2):

The Validation rule for this would be like below

```
ISPICKVAL(Type, "Other") && ISBLANK(Description__c)
```